# From which set is this bag? All grey 1x1 round bricks and 2x2 domes

Tags: set-identification

[image]
I received this bag together with a used set. It is bag number 1 and it says copyright from 2007. The content is >10 of round 1x1 bricks and 2x2 round dome bricks, in dark bluish gray and light bluish gray each.

These are very useful parts, but I wonder whether it is better not to open it when it comes from a valuable set.

Jncraton found it in 42055. Bag(s) 1 contain the dump truck and the debris.
[image]

However, I don't know why the bag says "2007".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's got to be the bag of aggregate from [Bucket Wheel Excavator (42055)](https://brickset.com/sets/42055-1/Bucket-Wheel-Excavator).

[image: 42055]

Comment: You are probably right, but why is the bag from 2007? The set was released in 2016.

Comment: The copyright of the bag design and printing is from 2007. They must have had some extra and used them in a batch of these sets. There are 2 newer bag designs, one from 2011 that looks virtually the same as the 2007 one, and one from 2017 with a white band down the middle.

Comment: Copyrighting designs for bags that are only used to convey the real product is a fine example of copyright failing to make the world any better.  The fact that LEGO patented the brick and the minifig and lived with the shorter timeframes afforded by patents is one of the things that makes me like them so much.

Answer (score 3):

I used to have this set and I believe it belongs to this set:

[image: here]

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE! This appears to be the correct answer. Thanks for sharing! If you end up getting voted down on this, it would likely be because your answer doesn't add much new information. It is helpful to know that you've had first-hand experience with this and remember this bag being in the set, though.